# For Loop Continue with a Condition

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, continue

I need to loop a function depending on the date/day. My code is as follows:

```
day = day_number = 1
start_date = datetime.strptime('10/01/20', '%m/%d/%y').date()

for day in range (1,6):
    if (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Saturday") or (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Sunday"):
        continue
    else:
        some_function()
        output = pd.to_excel("output_day_" + str(day_number)+".xlsx")
```

This function needs to be run for 5 days, starting from 10/01/20 as day = 1. But if the day is either Saturday or Sunday, it should skip them and move to the next business day. In this case, 10/03/20 and 10/04/20 would be day = 3 and day = 4 respectively and both are on the weekend. The loop should skip both day = 3 and day = 4 and go to day = 5.

Right now I'm getting the output for only day = 1. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you move your else logic inside `if not (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Saturday") or (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Sunday"):`

Comment: `start_date` never changes. At the bottom of the loop add one day to `start_date` using a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Pandas has pretty good datetime functionality including support for *business days*. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to increment the day and the counter for number of days.
I tested this code it works smooth. You need to the increment the day by 1.
edit1:

```
import datetime
day = day_number = 0
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('10/01/20', '%m/%d/%y').date()
for day in range (1,6):
    #print(start_date)
    day_number+=1
    if (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Saturday") or (start_date.strftime("%A")=="Sunday"):
        continue
    else:
        #some_function()
        print(day_number)
    start_date+= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: This has one problem. For 2020/10/05 it's still showing day = 3 because it skipped 2020/10/03 and 2020/10/04. Ideally, 2020/10/05 should be day = 5. When a date is skipped, day number should be skipped accordingly. Can you help me how to change this?

Comment: to increase the number of days without skipping just shift `day_number+=1` to the top that is above the if statement. This should do the change.

Comment: Yeah, I jut figured it out. But day 1 is missing as well. If you see my code, everyday should get output_day_(day_number).xlsx file. This seems to be excluding day 1 altogether. Right now I only get output_day_2, output_day_3 and so on. Output_day_1 is missing because I think it's not being considered at all.

Comment: the day needs to be incremented later as done in the edit to account for day1